# Does gzip hold any cache in memory or a temp file?

Tags: gzip, benchmarks

I'm doing some benchmarking on the compression of files with/without a hypervisor using gzip. The command I'm running to test how long a file takes to complete is :

```
time gzip -c filename.txt > filename.txt.gz
```

I'm a little confused, because the first time I run the command on a new file the time is always ~twice as long as any subsequent test until I reboot. For example:

```
1st run: .50 seconds
2nd run: .25 seconds
3rd run: .26 seconds
...
```

Why would there be such a difference in time? Does gzip store the compression in memory or somewhere else like a temp file?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `gzip` doesn't cache your files, Linux does. Any memory not required by running programs is used as a disk cache, and after the first time you read `filename.txt` it will be added to the cache. So provided it is not modified in the meanwhile, subsequently reading the file will get the copy already in memory, which probably accounts for the speed-up.